# Is there a way to capture heat from the air? (and potentially store it?)

Tags: thermodynamics

Is there a way to capture heat from the air (present in our surroundings)?
Also, can we store it?
If yes, how?  And if no, why?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99398/discussion-on-question-by-areen-is-there-a-way-to-capture-heat-from-the-air-an). Also, comments are for asking for clarifications and suggesting improvements to a post- please do not answer questions in comments.

Comment: Bleh I should have noticed this seemed familiar before I answered it.  Found pretty much an exact dupe with more comprehensive answers.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but possibly not in the ways you are thinking.

If you want to "capture" heat from the air and put it into somewhere at a lower temperature, that is very straightforward.  Heat will naturally transfer from hot to cold, so a cool space in thermal contact with warmer air will cause that space to heat up while the air cools down.

If you want to take heat from the air and capture it somewhere that is a higher temperature, you're going against the natural tendencies of heat transfer, and so you would need to do work to get the heat to go in that direction.  The most common example is a [heat pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_pump).

As far as storage goes, you would need to move the heated air into an insulated and sealed container.  As far as I'm aware, there is no perfect insulator for heat, so you cannot store that heat indefinitely, but an insulated container would at least give you temporary storage.

Comment: Hi, I want to convert the heat present in air to electricity. Any Remarks?

Comment: @Areen You should post it as a separate question

Comment: @Areen Not likely to work.  To turn heat into electricity you need a temperature _difference_.  You would need something that was always cooler than the air to dump your heat into.  Then you have to consider the consequences of heating up wherever you are dumping that heat.  To make it even worse, if the temperature difference is low, the electricity production is extremely inefficient.

Comment: @JMac Re, "Then you have to consider the consequences of heating up wherever you are dumping that heat." I don't understand this...

Comment: @Areen I believe that's a quip about climate change.

Comment: @Areen You should read about [heat engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_engine).

Comment: @JMac I agree with your answer except the reference of capturing heat and storing heat, since heat is only energy in transit. I know  you know (from past posts) that things don't contain heat and heat is  not something that is stored. I keep pounding on this because it took maybe more than 100 years to debunk the caloric theory of heat. I think you'd agree we need to emphasize to new learners of thermo what heat actually is.

Comment: @Areen For example, if you're taking heat from air and dumping it into cooler water, then that water is also going to heat up, so eventually it wouldn't be able to transfer any more heat.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking you cannot "capture heat" from air. And you cannot "store" heat regardless of where you get if from. Heat by definition in thermodynamics is the transfer of energy between things solely due to a temperature difference between them. What you are capturing from the air is some of its internal energy. Now, @JMac answer applies. You can capture the internal energy naturally (spontaneously) by heat transfer from the air to an environment at a lower temperature. Or, as @JMac said, you can transfer it to a higher temperature environment by doing external work (the heat pump).

Once the heat transfer occurs from the air to something else, the internal energy of that something else will increase (unless that something else does an equivalent amount of work, per the first law). The energy that was transferred is no longer identifiable as "heat".

Hope this helps.